# Is it possible to connect an Android phone to LMX9838 via Bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth, file-transfer

I'm working on a course project. We are making a circuit board, which has a LMX9838 chip connected to a ARM-based MCU. I want to make an application on Android to connect the smartphone to our board using bluetooth featured on the smartphone and LMX9838 Bluetooth controller. My app will be able to send command from the smartphone to the MCU via LMX9838 and it will be able to transfer data (e.g files) between the phone and the MCU too.

That's what I want to do. But I wonder if it is possible to connect bluetooth on the smartphone and the LMX9838 bluetooth controller? And if it is possible, how can I make it? I know my question is very unspecific but you guys could give me some hints about the basic step, please. Because I've never worked with bluetooth technology so my experience in it is nearly zero.

Anyone have any suggestion? Thanks in advance!

Comment: it would probably help if you linked us to that chip. I think the majority of the people here are not going to know what it is at all just based on the name of it. Anywho, it should be possible to connect yes, I will say though I had mixed success while trying to connect a different bluetooth communications chip with android devices. I found it to be about 50% success rate across the devices I attempted. So it may also be helpful for you to include which device specifically you are wanting.

Comment: Here is the link for that chip: http://www.ti.com/product/lmx9838
As you said, it's about 50% success rate. Why? And what is that rate dependent on?

Comment: I was never able to figure out why =/ I was using the [Blue Smirf](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10938) though, not the same specific chip as you've got. I never found a pattern as to why some worked and others didn't. I had multiple devices manufactured by HTC and samsung, and I would see success on a few of each, and fail on a few of each. It's been a while though so I don't recall exactly which ones worked.